A problem occured during the installation of 24.10
This was the error. I was not able to use Enter to continue.


It looks like you were trying to upgrade from another version of Ubuntu rather than install 24.10. Edit your question and provide details of the steps you have taken to upgrade Ubuntu. Also indicate, if this a server, or desktop version, if it is virtual, cloud, or real install. Without these details your question cannot be answered.
